# How can I sort a complex Python list?

Tags: python

I have a complex list of events and times that I want to sort. I want to have the events listed by the start time, so an event on April 1st goes before an event on April 2nd.

The problem is, is that the events are sorted in a (weird?) list that looks like this:

```py
all_events = [['My Event', 1588766400], 
              ['Cinco de Mayo', 1588636800], 
              ["Mother's Day", 1589068800], 
              ['Memorial Day', 1590364800], 
              ["Father's Day", 1592697600], 
              ['Independence Day observed', 1593734400], 
              ['Independence Day', 1593820800], 
              ['Tax Day', 1594771200], 
              ['Labor Day', 1599436800], 
              ['Columbus Day (regional holiday)', 1602460800], 
              ['Halloween', 1604102400]]
```

If you convert the epochs to RFC 2822, you can see the Cinco de Mayo is supposed to go first, then My Event. (I used https://coderstoolbox.net/unixtimestamp/)

I would have taken the times from `all_events` to another list by doing

```py
times = []

for event in all_events:
    times.append(event[1])
```

and then sort them using the Python [sorted()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_sorted.asp) function but then if I sort just the times, I wouldn't be able to keep track of the differences the the `times` list.

So is there a way to keep track of the differences in a list and apply the differences to another list? (Whoa, that was a mouthful)

Comment: What is the purpose of this question?

Comment: I believe you want `sorted(events, key=lambda x: x[1])`

Comment: If you're going to be performing some reasonably complex operations, why not use something like Pandas?

Comment: It's only going to be sorting a list that has up to 20 lists so up to 40 elements max. It's not like I need it ASAP...

Comment: Plus, I am running this on a Raspberry Pi 4B in conjunction with an LCD. I think writing to the LCD would be slower. :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just sort by the time:

```
sorted(all_events, key=lambda event: event[1])
```

or if you want to make it more verbose/explicit/well-typed:

```
from typing import List, Union

Event = List[Union[int, str]]  # [name: str, time: int]

def get_event_time(event: Event) -> int:
    assert isinstance(event[1], int)
    return event[1]

sorted(all_events, key=get_event_time)
```

Comment: Woah, I wasted a whole afternoon on the code I just wrote. I never really understood lambda functions though, how do they work?

Comment: Any time you find yourself implementing a sorting algorithm from scratch, you're wasting your own time (unless you're doing it for educational/entertainment value in which case have fun)!

Comment: I provided two versions of the code in anticipation of the `lambda` being unfamiliar to you.  :D  The `lambda` is just a way to define a function on the fly; it does the same exact thing as the `get_event_time` in my second version, but without a useful name or type checking.

Comment: So `lambda event: event[1]` is just returning the time in the `Event` list?

Comment: It's exactly like `get_event_time`: it's a function that returns the time (`event[1]`) from whatever `event` you pass it.  It doesn't on its own do anything with the event list, but passing it as a `key` to the `sorted` function causes it to get invoked on every element of the list to be sorted.  The value that it returns (the time) is used as the "key" for the sorting comparisons in place of the actual element.

Comment: Ah! Thanks for the clarification!
I really need to learn more things like these...